# Create a .exe file which show a graphe

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new in python community (and also on this site !) so normaly I don't ask for anwsers but try to find it by myself.
However, this time I do not find the answer by myself. That's why I request some help from you :)

Let me introduce the context...

I want to make a simple .exe file which is capable to show a graphe. Very basic stuff, but at the end it will be more complicated (ask for a data input in order to create graphe maybe, or stuff like that). But let's be simple first, in order to understand the problem.

So my main.py is a basic operation to illustrate the problem in an easy way.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1,10,0.1)
y = x**2

fig1 = plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x,y,label = 'test')
plt.xlabel(r"$ x $")
plt.ylabel(r"$ y $")
plt.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Then, to create a .exe file, we need a setup.py which can be seen below

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "D:\\Users\\Logiciel\\Anaconda\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "D:\\Users\\Logiciel\\Anaconda\\tcl\\tk8.6"

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
name = "test33",
version = "0.1",
options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["numpy","matplotlib"]}},
description = "This is test",
executables = [Executable("test.py")]
      )
```

And after that, I just run "python setup.py bluid" in the windows command to get my .exe file.

But of course it doesn't show the curve as I expected... It would have been to simple.. !

My question is the following one : 
How can I get an .exe file which create a curve (as you can do in Spyder IDE) by only running it. Do I have to create a GUI in order to do that ?

Thanks for the answer

Comment: Did you try using [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/)?

Comment: Yes I do
But it still doesn't work.
Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a special indication in your setup files to indicated a "platforms library". Here there's the code lines : *"include_files":[r"D:\Users\Logiciel\Anaconda\Library\plugins\platforms"]

```
setup(
name = "test33",
version = "0.1",
options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["numpy","matplotlib","tkinter","PIL"],"include_files":[r"D:\Users\Logiciel\Anaconda\Library\plugins\platforms"]}},
description = "This is test",
executables = [Executable("test.py")]
      )
```